# How does this unique file header 'special marker' tell eCryptfs that it's an eCryptfs file?

Tags: c, header, freepascal, ecryptfs

I am writing a program (using Free Pascal, not C) that parses the header of eCryptfs files.

One of the values in the header starts at byte 7 and ends at 15 (an 8 byte value). It is of use to me because it's a value that uniquely identifies the files as eCryptfs files. So I am trying to code my app to recognise it when it finds such values in files.

However, the marker itself is generated by XOR'ing a randomly generated 4 byte value (X) with another 4 byte static hex value of 0x3c81b7f5 (Y). The generated value is 4 bytes, Z. X + Z together form the 8 byte special marker. Y itself is not stored in the files header. So, seeing as the value 0x3c81b7f5 (Y) is never stored in the header, I can't code my application to look for it and seeing as the other 4 bytes are the XOR'd result of one static value with a another random one, I can't work out how it's recognised.

Having asked how the eCryptfs program recognises this value as "an eCryptfs file" at the eCryptfs Launchpad site (https://answers.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+question/152821, one of the community referred me to the relevant C source code which I have linked to below. However, I don't understand C well enough to work out how it is recognising the special markers. Can anyone help me so I can code the same kind of recognition process into my own app? I don't want source code but I just want someone to explain how the C code is working out "Ah yes, that's an eCryptfs file right there!" so I know what I need to code my app to do.

http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/fs/ecryptfs/crypto.c?v=linux-2.6;im=excerpts#L1029

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're really interested in is this part here:

```
m_1 = get_unaligned_be32(data);
m_2 = get_unaligned_be32(data + 4);
if ((m_1 ^ MAGIC_ECRYPTFS_MARKER) == m_2)
    return 1;
```

The [`get_unaligned_be32`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?v=linux-2.6;im=3;i=get_unaligned_be32) function just converts four bytes from 
`data` to an unsigned four byte integer with possible [byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order) 
adjustments. The `data + 4` in the second call to `get_unaligned_be32` 
moves the address passed to `get_unaligned_be32` up by four bytes:

```
[0][3][2][4][4][5][6][7]   
^           ^
data        data + 4
m_1         m_2          /* After adjusting byte order */
```

So, the first two lines just pull two unsigned integers out of the 
first eight bytes of `data` (possibly with byte order fixes).

Then we have this expression:

```
(m_1 ^ MAGIC_ECRYPTFS_MARKER) == m_2
```

The `^` is just the XOR operator and `MAGIC_ECRYPTFS_MARKER` is 
[0x3c81b7f5](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?v=linux-2.6;im=3;i=MAGIC_ECRYPTFS_MARKER) so this test is just XORing `m_1` and 0x3c81b7f5 and 
seeing if it is equal to `m_2`; if this comparison is true then you 
have the right type of file.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explin that in such detail. That's superb, thank you. I understand the code now.

Answer (score 1):

If by "X + Z together form the 8 byte special marker" you mean that they're concatenated, then you have the following:

```
Y = 0x3c81b7f5
X = some random value

Z = X ^ Y  (also a random value, due to X being random)
```

Now, you have X and Z from the file header. If you xor them together,the following relation holds:

```
X ^ Z = X ^ (X ^ Y) = Y
```

So you should end up with the value 0x3c81b7f5.

Comment: Thanks both of you. These answers combined have helped me no end! Thanks again.